# How to restore Oracle 11g database without controlfile and spfile for a new server?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rman, disaster-recovery

Hello everyone I have made a backup to my Oracle 11g dtabase with SID=ORCL

using the command `backup database plus archivelog` this my output after performing this command

`Starting backup at 10-SEP-17 using target database control file instead of recovery catalog allocated channel: ORADISK_1 channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=97 device type=DISK channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set input datafile file number=00001 name=C:\APP\MOD\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSTEM01.DBF input datafile file number=00002 name=C:\APP\MOD\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSAUX01.DBF input datafile file number=00003 name=C:\APP\MOD\ORADATA\ORCL\UNDOTBS01.DBF input datafile file number=00004 name=C:\APP\MOD\ORADATA\ORCL\USERS01.DBF channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 10-SEP-17 channel ORA_DISK_1: finished piece 1 at 10-SEP-17 piece handle=C:\APP\MOD\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\BACKUPSET\2017_09_10\O1_MF_NNNDF_TAG20170910T180005_DVBNVP2J.BKP tag=TAG20170910T180005 comment=NONE channel ORADISK_1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:02:55 channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set including current control file in backup set including current SPFILE in backup set channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 10-SEP-17 channel ORA_DISK_1: finished piece 1 at 10-SEP-17 piece handle=C:\APP\MOD\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\BACKUPSET\2017_09_10\O1_MF_NCSNF_TAG20170910T180005_DVBO16L3.BKP tag=TAG20170910T180005 comment=NONE channel ORA_DISK_1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:00:01 Finished backup at 10-SEP-17
RMAN>`

after I done this I copied  the whole Oracle root folder to external hard drive

I formatted the old server ...and I figure out that my configuration for `controlfile autobackup is off` which means the I only have database backup after I done this command `backup database plus archivelog` ...I'm searching many online tutorial but I don't know which one is suitable for me I'm really confused...I'm using windows.

Comment: > ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set including current
> control file in backup set including current SPFILE in backup set
> channel ORA_DISK_1

This seems to imply the controlfile and spfile were included in the backup?

Comment: If you copied the oracle home then the spfile will be in the dbs folder

Comment: Just a thought, you could create a pfile, using the pfile, startup nomount. Then log on to rman and restore controlfile, then with suitable restore command you can restore and recover db. Once db is opened, create a proper spfile. bounce and you are good to go.

Comment: can you suggest me a tutorial...I'm confused which tutorial useful to my senario ? because I'm not a DBA yet ...our DBA quit without notice .

Comment: @AndrewBrennan is it possible to create control files and spfiles for my new machine ...because I'm using now different machine with less RAM ...when I type startup force nomount ...I get out of memory .

Comment: You'll have to change the parameter in the spfile. Create a pfile from the spfile. Modify the memory parameters with a text editor. Then create a new spfile from the modified pfile.